# Is it possible to include and play an itunes podcast on my website with mediaelement.js?

Tags: itunes, mediaelement.js, podcast

i am looking for a standalone solution to include and play an itunes podcast on a non-cms website. found no real solution so far, except somebody who suggested medialement.js but no further info on how to implement it in order to play back an itunes podcast. does medialement.js support this feature? if not, is there any other solution on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since no one from mediaelements.js answered this or my request, I suppose that this is not possible with mediaelements.js.

after trying different approaches (several services I found online) and also reading through apple support/forum, I came to the conclusion that it is possibly not really wanted by apple to play and control an itunes podcast on a place other than itunes and/or supported apps/devices.

what we finally did was to create a rss feed of the same data/music/stream as posted/published on itunes and then creating a custom html5 media player to import all data from the feed XML, build this way a playlist and control the stream/podcast/musicplayback.